# If $n^2$ is odd, is $n$ odd?

Tags: integers

I don't really know how to solve the question: if $n^2$ is odd, is $n$ odd? I think it might be odd, because every equation I've done such as $5^2$, $3^2$, etc. End up as odd numbers, is the way I go about answering this question wrong?

Comment: Assume $n$ is not odd, then $n$ is even. Then $n^2$ would be even. Contradiction the original statement that $n^2$ is odd. Also, please use latex front.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format your posts.

Comment: @Frank That's not _really_ contradiction, that's contraposition with a contradiction shoe-horned in at the end.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that if n is even then $n^2$ is even and if n is odd then $n^2$ is odd?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106275/prove-that-if-n-is-even-then-n2-is-even-and-if-n-is-odd-then-n2-is-odd)

Comment: @Frank This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information.

Comment: @Blue This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way you go about answering the question is wrong for two reasons.

First reason is that there are infinitely many odd numbers, and checking them one by one you'll never be able to finish your proof.

Second reason is that you are checking wrong thing, you are picking an odd number $n = 3,5$ or some other and then checking if $n^2 = 3^2,5^2$ is odd, but you are asking: if $n^2$ is odd, is $n$ odd, the other direction.

You have to ask yourself this: can you find even $n$ such that $n^2$ is odd? The answer is no, because product of two even numbers is always an even number. Therefore, if $n^2$ is odd, so must be $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If n^2 is odd then n is odd.

This statement can be proved by proving its contrapositive i.e. p implies q is equivalent to ~q implies ~p.

So we can show if n is even then n^2 is even.

Proof:

If n is even then it can be expressed in the form n=2m for some positive integer m.

Now, n^2 = (2m)^2

```
     = 4m^2 

     =2(2m^2)

     =2k where, k=2m^2 is a positive integer.
```

Thus n^2 is also even.

So, n is even implies n^2 is even  proves that n^2 is odd implies n is odd.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, please do not rush to answer questions where the OP has shown no work of their own. When you do ask or answer, use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ^Answers help everyone reading these questions, not just the OP.  Any correct answer should be submitted.